# Namespace portable field references in LWC (Lightning Web Component) html markup

Tags: lightning-web-components, namespace

I've developed a Lightning Web Component (LWC) in a development org without a namespace but now must get it to work in a managed package I'm building which of course has a name space.  I get out to do the javascript part using the Schema to get the fields.  But, don't know how to deal with field reference in the html markup.

Consider the markup below.  It works in my dev org...

```
<template for:each={mySObjectList.data} for:item="iter">
    <tr class="slds-hint-parent" key={iter.Id}>

        <td data-label="Created Date" class="">
          <div class="slds-truncate " title={iter.CreatedBy.Name}>
            <lightning-formatted-date-time value={iter.CreatedDate} year="2-digit" month="2-digit" day="2-digit"
               hour="2-digit" minute="2-digit">
            </lightning-formatted-date-time>
          </div>
        </td>

        <td data-label="My Custom Field" class="w750">
            <div class="slds-truncate " >{iter.My_Custom_Field__c}</div>
        </td>

      </tr>
</template>
```

But to get it to work in the org with the namespace I must code --

```
            <div class="slds-truncate " >{iter.MyNamespacePrefix__My_Custom_Field__c}</div>
```

I'm hoping not to have to process my code to add the namespace prefix when moving from dev to packaging.   But I haven't found any reference on how to code the field reference in the markup to make it portable.

What I'm looking for would be analogous to the getSObjectValue() function that can run in the javascript.  But I need it on the html side in an iterator.